# How can I use gradients in custom Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I want to make the primary color of my custom sass Bootstrap as a gradient but when I define my custom variable as a gradient, I get an error that says

> "Error: $color: linear-gradient(to right, #c33764, #1d2671) is not a
>   color for **darken**."

Now, I get that darken is used for links later in the variables file and many other places which just means that the link color is a percentage darker of the primary color. How can I achieve this?

Here is my _custom.scss which is included as the first partial in bootstrap.scss:

```css
$celestial: linear-gradient(to right, #c33764, #1d2671);
$primary: $celestial;
```

Comment: Show the code, not just the error message...

Comment: @DavidG I added the code, will you be able to help me now?

Answer (score 1):

`linear-gradient` is only valid for the `background` css property and the `$primary` bootstrap variable expects a color.

What you'll want to do is target the element that you would like to apply the gradient on directly like this:

```
.navbar {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #c33764, #1d2671);
}
```

Comment: Hmm...I knew this. I have done this before. My main intention is to have all elements with the class primary to have a gradient.